# Expected type 'bool'. Found 'Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response'.intelephense(1006)

Tags: laravel, vscode-extensions, intelephense, laravel-10

I am working on a Laravel 10 on Visual Studio Code with intelephense extension installed. I am getting error on my policy classes saying,

```
Expected type 'bool'. Found 'Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response'.intelephense(1006)
```

Here is a portion of my code:

```
public function create(User $user): bool
{
    $roles = $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return in_array(Role::TRAINING_MANAGER, $roles)
        ? Response::allow()
        : Response::deny();
}
```

How to get ride of this error notification?

**Update**

I should have changed the return type to Response.

Comment: why are you setting the response to bool? it clearly says it returns a Response instance. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Response.php#L52

Comment: Laravel 10 provides default return types, and that is the default value.

Comment: Laravel policies has a HandlesAuthorization trait which handles the deny and allow for you, all what you need is to return true or false, check @Top-Master answer and choose the the solution you want

Comment: @N69S Sure, I should have changed the return type to Response.

Answer (score 3):

### If OP's `create(...)` is a route-handler (aka controller):

Simple, remove `: bool` of the controller/handler.

The line:

```
public function create(User $user): bool
```

Should be:

```
public function create(User $user)
```

### Else, try:

```php
public function create(User $user): bool
{
    $roles = $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return in_array(Role::TRAINING_MANAGER, $roles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) in the PHP documentation are well explained, in one read.

You are trying to return an Object, but you are typing the return as Boolean

**Returns Boolean**

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post): bool
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

**Returns the Object**

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post): Response
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny('You do not own this post.');
}
```